# Running a 32 bit assembly/C program on a 64 bit Mac

Tags: c, macos, assembly, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to test an assembly program with a C program as well, on my 64 bit mac, but all the code in assembly has to be in 32 bit format. I'm inputing in the terminal the standard cc -m32 -o prog cprogram.c assembly.s but it tells me it's not possible and then I put: sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib libc6-i386 lib6-dev-i386 to install the 32 bit libraries I think, and it tells me it's not possible because it cannot find the command: apt-get...
Any help? thanks

Comment: apt-get is a tool for Debian-style Linux, not OSX.  You will either need to figure out if/how you can build and run legacy 32-bit code on a 64-bit ersion of OSX, or run a compact Linux (perhaps most easily a 32-bit version) in a virtual machine.

Comment: Is it not possible to run 32 bit programs in a mac then?

Comment: There are actually two distinct questions: can you build them with the current toolchain, and can you run them.  I don't off the top of my head know the answer to either, but just because there might be support to *run* legacy versions doesn't mean that the stock toolchain will build them.

Comment: Try using `-arch i386` instead of  `-m32`.

Comment: Pedro - you can absolutely run 32 bit applications in 64 bit OS X.